# Have rvalue reference instead of forwarding reference with variadic template

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, rvalue-reference, forwarding-reference

I have a struct `X` and a function `foo` which must receive rvalue references of `X`.

At first I started with just one argument, and it was simple (oh... the simpler times):

```
auto foo(X&& arg) -> void {...};

X x;
foo(x);            // compile error [OK]
foo(std::move(x)); // accepted      [OK]
foo(X{});          // accepted      [OK]
```

But then I wanted to expand and accept a variable number of `X` arguments (still only rvalue rferences).

But there is a problem.

- 1st you cannot have `auto foo(X&&... args)` which would have been ideal
- 2nd Now you are forced to do `template <class... Args> auto foo(Args&&... args)` but now you end up with forwarding references, which will happily accept non-temporaries:

```
template <class... Args>
auto foo(Args&&... args) -> void { ... };

X x1, x2;
foo(x1, x2);                       // accepted [NOT OK]
foo(std::move(x1), std::move(x2)); // accepted [OK]
foo(X{}, X{});                     // accepted [OK]
```

Why they used this syntax and rules for forwarding references baffled me since the begging. This is one problem. The other problem with this syntax is that `T&&` and `X<T>&&` are completely different beasts. But we are getting off track here.

I know how to solve this with `static_assert` or `SFINAE` but both of these solutions complicate things a bit, and in my humble opinion should never have been needed if the language was designed right for once. And don't even get me started on `std::initializer_list` ... we are getting off track again.

So my question: is there a simple solution/trick I am missing by witch `Args&&` / `args` are treated as rvalue references?

---

Just as I was wrapping up this question, I thought I had a solution.

Add deleted overloads for lvalue references:

```
template <class... Args>
auto foo(const Args&... args) = delete;

template <class... Args>
auto foo(Args&... args) = delete;
```

Simple, elegant, should work, let's test it:

```
X x1, x2;

foo(x1, x2);                       // compile error [OK]
foo(std::move(x1), std::move(x2)); // accepted [OK]
foo(X{}, X{});                     // accepted [OK]
```

Ok, yeey, I have it!

```
foo(std::move(x1), x2);            // accepted [oh c'mon]
```

Comment: I will probably end up using SFINAE or static_assert since although I hope there is a better solution I doubt it. I am just exploring the language capabilities. If there is a duplicate, I apologize, I did not find it.

Comment: You ask for a solution, then disqualify the 2 most obvious solutions (`static_assert` or SFINAE). Why?

Comment: Completely agree w/ @Justin. The post looks more like a rant than a real question. Second solution would check only the first argument.

Comment: @Justin because I am not on a deadline, I am just working on my own pace. At such I can afford to search for the best solution and test the language capabilities before jumping to the workaround.

Comment: As for why your last idea doesn't work: You call `foo(std::move(x1), x2)`. The rvalue for the first argument prevents the selection of any of the reference-only overloads, but the template argument for the second argument can still be deduced to be a lvalue reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The* way to have a bunch of rvalue references is with SFINAE:

```
template <class... Args,
    std::enable_if_t<(!std::is_lvalue_reference<Args>::value && ...), int> = 0>
void foo(Args&&... args) { ... }
```

Fold-expressions are C++17, it is easy enough to write a metafunction to get that same behavior in C++14. This is your only option really - you want a constrained function template deducing to rvalue references, but the only available syntax is overloaded to mean forwarding references. We could make the template parameters non-deduced, but then you'd have to provide them, which seems like not a solution at all.

With concepts, this is of course cleaner, but we're not really changing the underlying mechanism:

```
template <class... Args>
    requires (!std::is_lvalue_reference<Args>::value && ...)
void foo(Args&&... args) { ... }
```

or better:

```
template <class T>
concept NonReference = !std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value;

template <NonReference... Args>
void foo(Args&&... ) { ... }
```

---

It's worth pointing out that neither of these work:

```
template <class... Args> auto foo(const Args&... args) = delete;
template <class... Args> auto foo(Args&... args) = delete;
```

because they only delete overloads that take *all* lvalue references, and you want to delete overloads that take *any* lvalue references.

Comment: that's what I was afraid of. I would have gone with `std::is_rvalue_reference<Args&&>::value` (or better yet `std::is_same<Args&&, X&&>::value`). Is there a reason you chose `!std::is_lvalue_reference<Args>` ?

Comment: @bolov They all mean the same thing, I just picked the one that made the most sense to me - since `Args` will either deduce to some `X` or some `Y&`, and we don't want the latter. You could also just do `!std::is_reference<Args>` if we're making a list.

Comment: @bolov Well, if you specifically wanted `X&&`, then you should use that - as that constraint is the most specific.

Comment: _This is your only option really_. Is [my reasoning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45515048/4987285) wrong or there exists another option actually? I cannot see flaws in the other solution, but you are more experienced than me and maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @skypjack You're doing exactly the same thing - constraining on all the arguments being rvalue references, just in a more roundabout way.

Comment: @Barry Well, not exactly. I don't use their const version after all. Instead you can use the _original_ type within `foo`. So, actually, you have not to remove any const from any type with the risk of getting an UB. In other terms I just test them with Justin's trick, then I've the original pack at my disposal. Am I wrong?

Comment: @skypjack Huh? What you're doing is constraining `foo()` by ensuring that `test()` is a valid call - `test()` is a valid call if forwarding everything in `args` yields rvalues - forwarding everything in `args` yields rvalues if none of the `Args` are lvalue reference types.

Comment: @Barry Oh, sorry, misunderstood your comment. You meant I did exactly the same thing you did with `std::is_lvalue_reference`. Good to know that it works then. Thank you. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

> I know how to solve this with static_assert or SFINAE but both of these solutions complicate things a bit [...] is there a simple solution/trick I am missing [...]?

There exists a pretty nice way you can do that without complicated SFINAE expressions or `static_assert`s. It also didn't require you to guess what parameters were const and what were not (it could quickly lead you to an UB if you try to play with constness of variables after all). Moreover you don't have to include `<type_traits>` for this, if you care about that.
It's based on [@Justin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45514384/4987285) that was almost there.

Let's see the code. Just use `decltype` and a test function for which you only require a declaration, no definition at all:

```
#include<utility>

template<typename... T>
void test(const T &&...);

template <class... Args>
auto foo(Args&&... args)
-> decltype(test(std::forward<Args>(args)...), void())
{}

struct X {};

int main() {
    X x1, x2;
    //foo(x1, x2);
    foo(std::move(x1), std::move(x2));
    foo(X{}, X{});
}
```

If you toggle the comment, the example won't compile anymore as requested.

The basic idea is almost the same discussed in the other answer around: if that's an rvalue reference, you can assign it to a const rvalue reference. Anyway, for you don't want to make const those parameters that were not const originally, just *test* them all together and then use the original ones.

Comment: I really like this trick. The `test` function is very reusable. You could make the function only usable in an unevaluated context, similar to `std::declval` (I'd probably just put an `= delete` to make it more clear that the function isn't intended to be used in an evaluated context).

Comment: @skypjack `= delete` doesn't exclude it from the overload set IIRC. The function gets selected, then the compiler says, "oh this was deleted, it can't be used"

Comment: @Justin Fair enough. You are right. I misused the terms but I hope you get the message. The result is the same anyway, [you cannot use it in an unevaluated context](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#dcl.fct.def.delete-2). So my example doesn't compile if I `= delete` it.

Comment: @skypjack Makes sense. I wonder how `declval` does it; they might just leave it unimplemented or use compiler support

Comment: @Justin It's defined by the language, so I would say it's all about implementation details. I don't think it could ever be an unimplemented function actually.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to avoid SFINAE, you can take your arguments by `const&&`; they won't be universal references:

```
template <class... Args>
auto foo(const Args&&... args) -> void { ... };
```

`const&&` can only be bound to rvalues, never to lvalues.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class... Args>
auto foo(const Args&&... args) -> void
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}

struct X {};

int main () {
    X x1, x2;
    // foo(x1, x2);                    // compile error
    foo(std::move(x1), std::move(x2)); // accepted [OK]
    // foo(std::move(x1), x2);         // compile error
    foo(X{}, X{});                     // accepted [OK]
}
```

[On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1d906417eb21596)

Unfortunately, you'd then have to cast away the `const`, so it's not the prettiest solution.

Comment: You'd have to cast away `const`... and then, how would you know which rvalues actually weren't `const` (making that safe) and which were (making it UB)?

Comment: @Barry Yeah, I definitely would recommend not doing it this way. But I can't think of an example in "normal" code where you would have a parameter to a function be `const&&`. The only way I can think of is to have a function return a `const&&`, which I don't see happening in "normal" code.

Comment: Safely casting away the `const` on rvalue parameter shouldn't be an issue. I highly doubt anyone would actually want `const` rvalue. Defeats the purpose of a rvalue.

Comment: @User10482 I wouldn't say that this shouldn't be an issue. Some examples: 1. consider a template taking forwarding references, but with accidental use of `std::move` instead of `std::forward`; bam! `const&&` for any `const&` parameters. 2. Suppose you have a `const` value which used to be non-`const` so it was `std::move`d into something, before it was refactored to be `const` (perhaps because there's no perf benefit for the type, perhaps because the `std::move` was missed): bam! `const&&` and therefore UB. 3. Suppose someone really likes using `std::move` to mark the last use of everything.

Comment: @Justin I understand one could end up with `const&&` purposely or by mistake. If done purposely, that defeats the intent of an `rvalue` reference (marked for moving). If it was supposed to be read-only in the first place `const&` would take care of that since it can bind to `rvalue`s.